# MS Publisher -- Can I selectively apply a style to text within a paragraph?

Tags: styles, microsoft-publisher

I'm formatting a textbook in Microsoft Publisher, and need to show new vocabulary in **bold**.  I was hoping to use a Character Style like I would in MSWord, but I don't see that in Publisher.  It seems that styles only apply to the full paragraph.

Am I missing something? Or can anyone tell me how to create a style that applies only to part of a paragraph?  Thank you!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer at the Microsoft Answers forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/character-styles/62f7003c-3a06-4e5b-a3bc-46fd1dbecff5), character styles cannot be defined in Publisher - a surprising omission, I agree.

Comment: Thank you, somehow I never found that post.  It seems pretty definitive. :( I was hoping there was a work-around out there.